# How can I convert a 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<ApplicationUser>> to IList<ApplicationUser>?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

In my project I want to display a list of users in a project. projects and users have a many to many relationship in the database. I query those users via

```
var users = dbcontext.Projects.Select( u => u.Users);
```

this gives me an object of type IQueryable> but the display model requires a type of IList something that I can easily display on a view page.

Please SO how can I convert between the two or any helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `SelectMany()` to flatten the list and `ToList()` to convert it to list:

```
var users = dbcontext.Projects.SelectMany( u => u.Users).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm new to the system and msdn is not very helpful in clearing this up